# Parsing specific columns of CSV in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

so I have this CSV and I would like to do the following:

**Original data:**

[image]

**Parsed Data:**

[image]

So, to put in words, if a column has commas then I want to create a new column with only one value and delete the column which has multiple values.

> For example: N2 has I1, I3 and I4. Hence the new data gets 3 columns, containing one value only.

I want to make it dynamic in such a way that all the permutations are reflected. **Like in the case of N3 that has 2 places and 2 items.**

I am trying to use python's pandas to do this. Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: for the first row the comma after I1 is not an error? all unique values in item finish by a comma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another option:

```
df['Place'] = df['Place'].str.split(',')
df['Item'] = df['Item'].str.split(',')

exploded = pd.DataFrame([
    a + [p, t] for *a, P, T in df.values
    for p in P for t in T
], columns=df.columns)
```

And the output:

```
  Name Place Item
0   N1    P1   I1
1   N2    P2   I1
2   N2    P2   I3
3   N2    P2   I4
4   N3    P2   I2
5   N3    P2   I5
6   N3    P3   I2
7   N3    P3   I5
```

Answer (score 0):

You are effectively attempting to take the Cartesian product of each row, then binding the result back into a `DataFrame`. As such, you could use `itertools` and do something like

```
from itertools import chain, product
df_lists = df.applymap(lambda s: s.split(','))
pd.DataFrame(chain.from_iterable(df_lists.apply(lambda row: product(*row), axis=1)), columns=df.columns)
```

With your example input:

```
In [334]: df
Out[334]:
  Name  Place      Item
0   N1     P1        I1
1   N2     P2  I1,I3,I4
2   N3  P2,P3     I2,I5

In [336]: df_lists = df.applymap(lambda s: s.split(','))

In [337]: pd.DataFrame(chain.from_iterable(df_lists.apply(lambda row: product(*row), axis=1)), columns=df.columns)
Out[337]:
  Name Place Item
0   N1    P1   I1
1   N2    P2   I1
2   N2    P2   I3
3   N2    P2   I4
4   N3    P2   I2
5   N3    P2   I5
6   N3    P3   I2
7   N3    P3   I5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `iterrows()` :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['N1', 'N2', 'N3'], 'Place':['P1', 'P2','P2,P3'], 'Item':['I1,', 'I1,I3,I4', 'I2,I5']})

result = pd.DataFrame()
new_result = pd.DataFrame()

df['Place'] = df['Place'].apply(lambda x: x.strip(','))
df['Item'] = df['Item'].apply(lambda x: x.strip(','))

for a,b  in df.iterrows():
    curr_row = df.iloc[a]
    temp  = ((curr_row['Place'].split(',')))
    for x in temp:
        curr_row['Place'] = x
        result = result.append(curr_row, ignore_index=True)

for a,b  in result.iterrows():
    curr_row = result.iloc[a]
    temp  = ((curr_row['Item'].split(',')))
    for x in temp:
        curr_row['Item'] = x
        new_result = new_result.append(curr_row, ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
  Name Place Item
0   N1    P1   I1
1   N2    P2   I1
2   N2    P2   I3
3   N2    P2   I4
4   N3    P2   I2
5   N3    P2   I5
6   N3    P3   I2
7   N3    P3   I5
```

This is the simplest way you can achieve your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the use of pandas. If you want to stick with the standard `csv` module, you simply have to split each field on comma (`','`) and then iterate on the splitted elements.

Code could be **assuming the input delimiter is a semicolon (`;`)** (**I** cannot know what it is except it cannot be a comma):

```
with open('input.csv', newline='') as fd, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as fdout:
    rd = csv.DictReader(fd, delimiter=';')
    wr = csv.writer(fdout)
    _ = wr.writerow(rd.fieldnames)
    for row in rd:
       for i in row['Item'].split(','):
           i = i.strip()
           if len(i) != 0:
               for p in row['Place'].split(','):
                   p = p.strip()
                   if len(p) != 0:
                       for n in row['Name'].split(','):
                           n = n.strip()
                           if len(n) != 0:
                               wr.writerow((n,p,i))
```

Output is:

```
Name,Place,Item
N1,P1,I1
N2,P2,I1
N2,P2,I3
N2,P2,I4
N3,P2,I2
N3,P3,I2
N3,P2,I5
N3,P3,I5
```